# postfix: automatically save emails as eml or msg in a separate folder

Tags: postfix-mta, dovecot, eml, procmail, mta

For my business activity I have a very simple Debian + Postfix + Dovecot mail server.

- Mails are saved under `/var/mail/` in an MBox file.
- procmail is not installed.
- For spam filtering I have a mail gateway - scrollout on a virtual machine.
- Mail users are Linux users, so there is no mysql or database connection.

What I want is that a specific account's emails will be stored in a format like eml or msg in a folder on my NAS. This is useful for me for several reasons.

I know that this will be done through Procmail... but I don't know the right way.

Comment: I don't see how Procmail would be necessary or useful here.  Just configure a different mailbox location for this particular user.  http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailLocation#Per-user_mail_locations and/or http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Namespaces#Mixed_mbox_and_Maildir

Comment: With that, I think this is better suited for https://serverfault.com/ -- nominating for migration.

Answer (score 0):

This particular user could have a simple `.procmailrc` which specifies

```
DEFAULT=/path/to/your/NAS/dir
```

but as indicated in comments, I don't think Procmail is really necessary or useful here.

(Specifying a directory just tells Procmail to save a unique file in the directory.  Add a trailing slash to make Procmail deliver to a Maildir with the customary `new`, `tmp`, and `cur` subdirectories; or a trailing slash and a dot to have the next available numbered file à la MH.  See [*procmailrc*(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/procmailrc) for details.)